# How can I sort a VB.NET DataView based upon data row substring?

Tags: vb.net, substring, dataview

I have this:

```
Dim strS As String = ""
Dim strRowFilter As String = "SID=" & strSID
Dim dv As DataView = objDataSet.Tables(1).DefaultView
dv.RowFilter = (strRowFilter)
dv.Sort = ("RIGHT(SName, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(' ' + RTRIM(SName))) - 1)")
For Each objDataRow As DataRow In dv
            'build strS
        Next

Return strS
```

`SName` is a String of format `Firstname Midname Lastname` (Midname optional), and I need to sort by `Lastname`.  I know there are special cases like 'Mike St. Cloud' but I'm fine with sorting on the last word.  The above code is giving me `System.IndexOutOfRangeException occurred:  Cannot find column RIGHT(SName.`

I got the sort term from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13610627/1810544), which works as an `ORDER BY` in SQL Server. I'm out of my depth with this one, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not an `ArrayList`, it's a `DataView`.

Comment: Good point, Edited.  I changed tactics partway through composing the question.  Apologies.

Comment: I thought you have already asked a question similar to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934925/how-can-i-sort-the-contents-telerik-gridboundcolumn-based-upon-a-substring). Can't you apply the same method I gave you?

Comment: If so, I don't see how. Again I need to avoid modifying the SP, and your code:   `If Not IsDBNull(row!NameList) Then
        Dim nameparts() As String = Cstr(row!NameList).Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If nameparts.Count > 0 Then
            row!lastname = nameparts.GetUpperBound(0)
        End If
    End If` only makes partial sense to me.  How do I use it in this case?  My final string will look like this: `"- <a>Firstname Lastname</a><br />- <a>Firstname Lastname</a><br />- <a>Firstname Lastname</a><br />..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx), the `Sort` property is:

> A string that contains the column name followed by "ASC" (ascending) or "DESC" (descending). Columns are sorted ascending by default. Multiple columns can be separated by commas.

Since, some of the classes in the `System.Data` namespace allow using SQL-like syntax for some things (such as the `DataTable.Select` method), people often are confused into thinking that all SQL syntax is supported.  That is not the case.  In this case, the `Sort` property supports very narrow functionality.  It can only be set to one or more column names (and the `ASC` or `DESC` order specifier).  It does not support functions like `RIGHT` and `LEFT`.

If you really want to sort using the `DataView`, you could add an additional column to the data which contains the string by which you want to sort the view.  When you select the data into the `DataSet`, you could use all of those SQL string manipulation methods to build the sort strings to select into that sort column.

However, I unless you really need to do it that way, I would recommend just creating an `Array` or `List` of the data and then sort that.  When you do it that way, you have access to all the string manipulation methods of .NET, which are more powerful and easier to read. For instance:

```
Dim names As New List(Of String)()
For Each row As DataRow In objDataSet.Tables(1).Rows
    names.Add(CStr(row("SName")))
Next
names.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Split().Last.CompareTo(y.Split().Last))
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Dim strS As String = ""
Dim dt As DataTable = objDataSet.Tables(1)

' create a lambda expression to split the name by " "
Dim splitName = Function(name As String) name.Split(" "c).Where(Function(s) s <> "")

' select rows that meet the SID filter and SName <> null and SName <> "",
' and get the SID, construct the FirstName and LastName,
' and of course, sort the return collection by LastName
Dim sortedrows = From row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                 Where (Not IsDBNull(row!SName) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CStr(row!SName)))
                 And CStr(row!SID) = strSID 
                 Select PersonID = row!PersonID,
                 FirstName = splitName(CStr(row!SName)).FirstOrDefault,
                 LastName = splitName(CStr(row!SName)).LastOrDefault
                 Order By LastName

' finally, construct the <a> tags as required from above
For Each row In sortedrows
    strS &= String.Format("<a href=""javascript: ViewPersonId({0}); return false;"">{1} {2}</a><br />", row.PersonID, row.FirstName, row.LastName)
Next
```

If the DataTable contains the following rows:

```
dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Travolta")
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Jack The Ripper")
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Beyonce")
dt.Rows.Add(4, " ")
dt.Rows.Add(5, "")
dt.Rows.Add(6, DBNull.Value)
```

Let's say they all meet the SID filter, it will return:

```
<a href="javascript: ViewPersonId(3); return false;">Beyonce Beyonce</a><br />
<a href="javascript: ViewPersonId(2); return false;">Jack Ripper</a><br />
<a href="javascript: ViewPersonId(1); return false;">John Travolta</a><br />
```

As you can see, `"Beyonce"` appears as `"Beyonce Beyonce"`. If you don't want this behavior, it can be changed by checking if FirstName = LastName in the `For Each` loop and execute an alternate code to construct the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks.  The above approach is the best fit for me, but I have a similar problem that I think I can solve with this.  Much appreciated.